# Camera stacking for first-person view weapon in Universal Render Pipeline

Tags: unity, rendering, camera, first-person-shooter

I just added URP to my project then upgraded the materials to URP and now it's not rendering the environment anymore

[image: Screenshot of scene and game view]

[image: Camera settings in inspector]

I found the problem is that I have 2 cameras which are stacking on each other:  one with a priority of 1 and the other 0 . The camera that has higher priority is blocking the lower priority camera.

How can I fix that? I want to render the higher priority camera on top of the lower priority one.

Comment: What should your environment look like instead? Can you show us how its material is configured?

Comment: @DMGregory well it should look like the Scene view and the material is simple here is image https://imgur.com/a/vp5OvJk

Comment: Great. Next, can you edit your question to show the configuration of your camera, your rendering settings, and your render pipeline asset?

Comment: @DMGregory I found the problem can you help me with that?

Comment: Sounds like you should edit your question to include how you've configured both cameras. Is it safe to assume you've [configured your stack as documented here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.2/manual/camera-stacking.html)?

Comment: @DMGregory well yeah I had to stack the cameras properly, anyways thank you :)

Comment: If you've solved your problem, write up your solution as an Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I was overlaying cameras on each other in the SRP so, in order to make it work in URP, I just had to Stack them properly
[link to documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.2/manual/camera-stacking.html)

Comment: This answer would be even better with a description of the steps you had to take to implement this.